# How to use Aho-Corasick to find a piece of text in given set of strings?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, aho-corasick

I have the code of the Aho-Corasick algorithm. But I still don't understand how to use the state information during the find procedure when searching for a text in a given list of strings.

For example I have a list of strings `[MOSCOW][COLA]`, and now I need to determine if `CA` is in the list, and if yes what is its position?

Here is a [link to the code](http://pastebin.com/AYUePCRF).

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm that you are studying works quite the opposite way.  If the dictionary is `[MOSCOW][COLA]`, and the input string is `CA`, then the algorithm will tell you all locations of `MOSCOW` in `CA`, and also all locations of `COLA` in `CA`.

Now a particular state (or, `Node`, as the linked code calls it), has a meaning something like: "*We might be just after the only `C` in `COLA`, but we definitely are not anywhere in the middle of `MOSCOW`*".  (This might be a node visited after the first character of `CA`.)

The power of the algorithm is easier to see when searching a different input, say, `MOSCOLONI`.  Just before seeing the `L`, the current state will mean "*We might be 5 characters into a potential `MOSCOW`, or 2 characters into a potential `COLA`*"  The big thing is that the state looks at all the dictionary words at once; in fact, even into all positions in all the words when you consider repeating characters as well.